# Different results for 2 subset data methods in R

Tags: r, subset

I'm subseting my data, and I'm getting different results for the following codes:

```
subset(df, x==1)
df[df$x==1,]
```

`x`'s type is `integer`

Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You are right that `x` has 2 type of values: 1 or NA.. (I forgot to mention it).. but why is that happened? (Using `subset` the results are fine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without example data, it is difficult to say what your problem is. However, my hunch is that the following probably explains your problem:

```
df <- data.frame(quantity=c(1:3, NA), item=c("Coffee", "Americano", "Espresso", "Decaf"))
df
quantity      item
       1    Coffee
       2 Americano
       3  Espresso
      NA     Decaf
```

Let's subset with `[`

```
df[df$quantity == 2,]
 quantity      item
        2 Americano
       NA      <NA>
```

Now let's subset with `subset`:

```
subset(df, quantity == 2)
quantity      item
       2 Americano
```

We see that there is a difference in sub-setting output depending on how `NA` values are treated. I think of this as follows: With `subset`, you are explicitly stating you want the subset for which the condition is **verifiably** true. `df$quantity==2` produces a vector of true/false-statements, but where quantity is missing, it is impossible to assign `TRUE` or `FALSE`. This is why we get the following output with an NA at the end:

```
df$quantity==2
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE    NA
```

The function `[` takes this vector but does not understand what to do with `NA`, which is why instead of `NA Decaf` we get `NA <NA>`. If you prefer using `[`, you could use the following instead:

```
df[which(df$quantity == 2),]
quantity      item
       2 Americano
```

This translates the logical condition `df$quantity == 2` into a vector or row numbers where the logical condition is "verifiably" satisfied.

Comment: As I wrote in the comment above.. you're right. Can you say what is the reason for that difference? Tks!

Comment: I have added a small note on that to my answer which may be helpful in remembering which one is which. I think it is more of a convention in `base R`, though we see that in add-on packages as e.g. with `dplyr::filter`, `NA`s are also excluded. I actually think the convention is helpful as it keeps me on my toes in looking out for missing values, but in the end it is a matter of taste, I would presume.