# Avoid NA values when subsetting a data frame

Tags: r, datetime, subset

I'm trying to get the time at which the maximum temperature for a given day was recorded but I have a problem when NA is present on the temperature column.

I get the max value for temperture with this code

```
tmax.today<-max(datos.today$temp,na.rm=TRUE)
```

and try to get its time with

```
hora.tmax.today<-datos.today$hora[datos.today$temp == tmax.today]
```

The object class is

```
class(hora.tmax.today)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

and its values are

```
hora.tmax.today
[1] NA                     NA                     NA                    
[4] NA                     NA                     NA                    
[7] "0-01-01 12:00:00 UTC"
```

But it should have only a value, the last one (don't worry about the date, I only need the time). If I look at the data there are six rows in the dataset with NA for temperature. How can I avoid the NA values?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `datos.today$hora[datos.today$temp == tmax.today & !is.na(datos.today$temp)]`.

Comment: Or, you can also, `hora.tmax.today<- hora.tmax.today[!is.na(hora.tmax.today)]`

Comment: Or use `which`. See the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782875/different-results-for-2-subset-data-methods-in-r/43783091#43783091

Comment: Suggestion from @lmo worked fine, had tried !is.na but couldn't find the right way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `which`. This returns he position index for the member of the vector which meets the condition. See the usage below.

```
hora.tmax.today<-datos.today$hora[which(datos.today$temp == tmax.today)]
```

Comment: Thanks for writing up my comment as an answer. @pacomet, have a look at the link I posted in the comments, which should explain why it sometimes works without `which`.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment by lmo the right command is

```
datos.today$hora[datos.today$temp == tmax.today & !is.na(datos.today$temp)]
```